# Xpath - numeric comparison fails for sequence of nodes, only uses first node

Tags: c#, xpath

I've found that when using the "number" function in an Xpath expression, the function only uses the first node in a sequence. An example of the issue:

```
using System.Xml;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
            doc.LoadXml(
@"<baseball>
    <games>
        <game>
            <id>1</id>
            <stadiumId>7</stadiumId>
            <attendance>4999</attendance>
        </game>
        <game>
            <id>2</id>
            <stadiumId>5</stadiumId>
            <attendance>600</attendance>
        </game>
        <game>
            <id>3</id>
            <stadiumId>5</stadiumId>
            <attendance>789</attendance>
        </game>
    </games>
    <stadiums>
        <stadium><id>5</id><capacity>1000</capacity></stadium>
        <stadium><id>7</id><capacity>5000</capacity></stadium>
        <stadium><id>9</id><capacity>560</capacity></stadium>
    </stadiums>
</baseball>");

            printNodes("what stadiums had games occur in them?",
                doc.SelectNodes("/baseball/stadiums/stadium[./id/text()=/baseball/games/game/stadiumId/text()]"));

            printNodes("what stadiums had games occur in them? this time converting to numbers before doing comparison",
                doc.SelectNodes("/baseball/stadiums/stadium[number(./id/text())=number(/baseball/games/game/stadiumId/text())]"));
        }//Main

        private static void printNodes(string description, XmlNodeList nodeList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----" + description + "-------");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        }       
    }//class
}//namespace
```

The output is:

```
-----what stadiums had games occur in them?-------
<stadium><id>5</id><capacity>1000</capacity></stadium>
<stadium><id>7</id><capacity>5000</capacity></stadium>
-------------------
-----what stadiums had games occur in them? this time converting to numbers before doing comparison-------
<stadium><id>7</id><capacity>5000</capacity></stadium>
-------------------
```

The reason it only returns stadium 7 in the second output (despite the Xpath queries being logically identical) is because the first baseball/games/game node has a stadiumId of 7. No other game nodes are evaluated.

Is this expected functionality for the number function? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `number` by design converts only first element in node-set - see [number in XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number).

Second: 
`=` in XPath is more like "any pair matches" instead of "both sides are equal". So you first statement is true because there is *an element* in "games/game" that matches "stadium" by "id", the second does not work as you expect because list of "games/game/stadiumId" nodes converted by "number" function becomes just ID of first one in the list (see above).

If you are going to write many XPath expressions please read the specification, at least the [Booleans](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) section that defines how "=" works.

Answer (score 2):

**If you really want to compare as numbers, in XPath 2.0 you can use**:

```
  /*/stadiums/*
        [xs:integer(id) = /*/games/*/stadiumId/xs:integer(.)]
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
  "/*/stadiums/*
         [xs:integer(id) = /*/games/*/stadiumId/xs:integer(.)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<baseball>
    <games>
        <game>
            <id>1</id>
            <stadiumId>7</stadiumId>
            <attendance>4999</attendance>
        </game>
        <game>
            <id>2</id>
            <stadiumId>5</stadiumId>
            <attendance>600</attendance>
        </game>
        <game>
            <id>3</id>
            <stadiumId>5</stadiumId>
            <attendance>789</attendance>
        </game>
    </games>
    <stadiums>
        <stadium>
            <id>5</id>
            <capacity>1000</capacity>
        </stadium>
        <stadium>
            <id>7</id>
            <capacity>5000</capacity>
        </stadium>
        <stadium>
            <id>9</id>
            <capacity>560</capacity>
        </stadium>
    </stadiums>
</baseball>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the results of this evaluation (the selected elements) are copied to the output**:

```
<stadium>
            <id>5</id>
            <capacity>1000</capacity>
</stadium>
<stadium>
            <id>7</id>
            <capacity>5000</capacity>
</stadium>
```